# Apply Icc color profile in xubuntu

Tags: display, color-management, icc

How to apply icc color profile in xubuntu 18.04 ? I am trying to use xcalib but only thing i am getting is "Error - unsupported ramp size 0".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the settings manager to load an icc profile as follows:

1. Goto Settings->Devices->Color
2. Choose your monitor (e.g. Laptop screen)
3. At the bottom of the panel, choose 'Add profile' to load an existing profile or import another
4. You can then select that new profile or another for your display

If you want more functionality, I highly recommend dispcal which is a GUI for the Argyll color management system.  It's really fun to use and has a large feature set.  For example, not only can you manage and manually adjust your profiles, the system integrates with many colorimeters. The package is `dispcalgui`, e.g. `sudo apt install dispcalgui`.  There is also the gnome color manager (`gcm`) but this is harder to use IMHO.

Comment: Clearly, this is not an answer for Xubuntu, which employs the XFCE desktop environment. Settings→Devices→Color is not available in Xubuntu.

Comment: The second part is fine for Xubunut, though. After installing "dispcalgui" all tools are available in start->Graphics. There are several tools and its worth to check them out. However, one should know a little bit about what an ICC is and how its used. I can confirm that you could create a monitor profile with external devices very easly. I used an x-rite device.